# unity move object over time using Coroutine wont move the object precisely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a border to idict which character was selected, and I want to move that when user click on specific character avatar, I think doing a smooth moving of the selecter border will be neat effect. Here is what is looks like:

[image]

So I am using following script to move the dashed border

```
public class SelectCharacter : MonoBehaviour, IInputBehavior {

    [SerializeField]
    private Character character;


    private IEnumerator moveLocalPosOverSeconds(GameObject obj,  Vector3 end, float seconds)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 start = obj.transform.localPosition;
        while(elapsedTime < seconds)
        {
            obj.transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, (elapsedTime / seconds));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        // hope this will ajust the dashed box to precise postion
        transform.localPosition = end; 
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        GameObject selectBorder = transform.parent.Find("SelectBorder").gameObject;
        Vector3 newLocalPos = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, selectBorder.transform.localPosition.y, selectBorder.transform.localPosition.z);
        Debug.Log("localPos is :" + newLocalPos);
        StartCoroutine(moveLocalPosOverSeconds(selectBorder, newLocalPos, 0.2f));
        SceneController.instance.ChangeCharacterTo(character);

    }
}
```

And it seems that the position of the border wont end up to the precisely postion as desired, I know that doing `Lerp` with time may case some precise position so add `transform.localPosition = end;` to last in hoping for ajust the postion after the `while` block. but it won't work.

And I double check the log of the console and the postion flied of the dashed box in ther inspector, it just won't end up in the precise position.

some time this will happen:

[image]

And if I got luck this seems to be good:

[image]

But in the inspector:

[image]

The x value should be precisely 0.9 instead of 0.88...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Incrementing elapsedTime BEFORE changing the position should help.

Comment: @FLX I am wondering why the last line of the coroutine won't tweak the position to its precisely desire

Comment: Every frame you move your sprite for the distance corresponding to the deltaTime of the PREVIOUS frame. The very last frame is completely ignored. There is nothing to wonder you get different, but always incorrect, results.

Comment: @rs232 why the last line of `transform.localPosition = end; ` won't do the tweak?

Comment: @armnotstrong I see, I think you should replace this last line with transform.localPosition = new Vector3(end.x, end.y, end.z); I'm not skilled enough to explain you the details but you can't assign a struct directly, you need to create a new one.

Comment: But don't forget to move elapsedTime as well because it's wrong

Comment: @FLX Ok I'll dig into that, thanks bro.

Comment: @FLX @rs232 I made a silly mistake that in the last line I change the `localPosition` of `transform` instead of `obj.transform` , that's why it will not tweak the position precisely, but your comment of move elapsedTime before the movement did help. Thanks again and sorry for the trouble, will delete this question.

Comment: Ok, nice then. I was wrong about assignation, apparently it's something about struct properties and not the struct itself, unrelated